# How can I solve problem with execute two stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wanted to exec two stored procedures nested but I don't have much information about it. I created T-SQL code below, it doesn't work. Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance.

```
DECLARE @currency_val decimal(18, 2);
DECLARE @first_price decimal(18, 2) = 80;
DECLARE @curr_unit nvarchar(50) = 'eur';

BEGIN
     exec sp_TLKARSILIK @first_price, @curr_unit @currency_val = @currency_val
END

BEGIN
    exec sp_DOVIZKARSILIK @currency_val, 'eur'
END
```

Comment: How does 'it doesn't work'?  Does it hang, do you get an error, no results, wrong results?  Please provide more information.

Comment: nested? that means sp_DOVIZKARSILIK will be called inside sp_TLKARSILIK ?

Comment: @mcalex, I doesn' t access to database, I have to use it at web page. But it doesn't work and give result

Comment: @AIMINPAN, yes I wanted to take return value of sp_TLKARSILIK and use it at sp_DOVIZKARSILIK

Comment: I realise there is a language barrier here but please try to explain what the issue is, without using the words "doesn't work". Does it throw an error? Or does it run and return no values? You need to test this in SSMS and confirm whther or not it works there before you add the web page to the equation. The proc might be fine and there might be an error with your web page

Comment: `exec sp_TLKARSILIK @first_price, @curr_unit @currency_val = @currency_val` This has a syntax error. You are missing a comma. Presumably one of these is an output parameter - something others have guessed but I will not.

Comment: @SMor, I used this T-Sql code in an apllication. And it doesn't works even with comma. Below code returns value but only first store procedure giving result. `exec @currency_val = sp_TLKARSILIK @first_price, @curr_unit  exec sp_DOVIZKARSILIK @currency_val, 'eur'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the output of first store procedure as input of second, it should like this:

```
declare @ouput1 as int

begin
    exec sp_first 'what_ever', @output1 output
    exec sp_second @output1
end
```

note the "output" descriptor for the @output1 parameter.

Comment: Use of BEGIN/END block has no purpose here. Suggest you start writing, teaching, and encouraging best practices by using statement terminators. It does not help to use names and procedure signatures that are completely different from those provided by OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the value of the second SP input parameter is not correct. This is because both SPs run simultaneously. The second SP must be run after the completion of the first SP. You can use a while statement to do this.

You can test the following code:

```
    DECLARE @currency_val decimal(18, 2) = -1;
    DECLARE @first_price decimal(18, 2) = 80;
    DECLARE @curr_unit nvarchar(50) = 'eur';
    
    BEGIN
         exec sp_TLKARSILIK @first_price, @curr_unit @currency_val = @currency_val
    END
    
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
IF @currency_val <> -1
BREAK
END
    BEGIN
        exec sp_DOVIZKARSILIK @currency_val, 'eur'
    END
```

Comment: Hello @Mostafa, I tried your code but unfortunatelly it returns only first result of SP.

Comment: What is the value of @currency_val after running the first SP?

Comment: value is 1401.6 TL

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the code execution and output?

Comment: _both SPs run simultaneously_ This is completely wrong. There is no way to execute tsql code in parallel using tsql.